# How is OID 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d parsed as 1.2.840.113549?

Tags: openssl, certificates, asn.1

I saw that an RSA key, created by OpenSSL, contains the following HEX string:

> 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01

that HEX string gets interpreted as Object ID:

> 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1

It is obvious 01 01 01 is 1.1.1, but how does 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d get interpreted (parsed) as 1.2.840.113549?

Comment: Please do not reject the question as a dump of ciphertext with known plaintext asking for the decryption algorithm; it is actually about a convention commonly used in real-world cryptography, and elsewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question's bytestring `2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01` is the Value field of an [ASN.1 BER/DER TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#Encoding_Structure) with type 6, which is the Object IDentifier for an RSA key (the Type and Length just before are coded as `06 09`, and won't be further discussed).

In order to parse that Value bytestring, we first separate the bytes into blocks ending after each byte in which the high-order bit is clear (in other words: blocks end after a byte in range 00<sub>h</sub> to 7f<sub>h</sub>). Then we paste together the low-order 7 bits of the bytes (in big-endian/reading order); so that
`_____2a|_____86_____48|_____86_____f7_____0d|_____01|_____01|_____01`   becomes
`0101010|00001101001000|000011011101110001101|0000001|0000001|0000001`

We then interpret each block of bits as coding a non-negative integer in big-endian binary. The question's example now comes out as the six integers: 42 840 113549 1 1 1

There's a special case for the first integer: it was built as $z=40x+y$, with $x$ encoding the top-level authority that assigned $y$. Integer $x$ is always one of $0$ (for *ccitt*), $1$ (for *iso*) or $2$ (for *joint-iso-ccitt*), and if $x<2$ then $y<40$.
We thus replace the first integer $z$ by $x=\min(\lfloor z/40\rfloor,2)$ and $y=z-40x$.
Note: when $x=2$, $y$ can be arbitrarily large. Assigned $y$ include [40](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.40) (exercising the $\min$ rule), [48](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.48) (requiring coding $z$ over more than one byte), and [999](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.999) (with $y\ge2^8$), which might not be correctly handled by some existing software.

The question's example now comes out as the seven integers: 1 2 840 113549 1 1 1

One practice is to format these integers in decimal without a leading `0` digit (with the exception of the integer zero represented as `0`), separated by dots, as in
`1.2.840.113549.1.1.1`
or sometimes enclosed in braces with separating spaces, as in
`{1 2 840 113549 1 1 1}`
or sometimes (as shown by the [OID Repository](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1))
`{iso(1) member-body(2) us(840) rsadsi(113549) pkcs(1) pkcs-1(1) rsaEncryption(1)}`
or in [OID-IRI notation](http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm#iri)
`/ISO/Member-Body/840/113549/1/1/1`

The careful reader will notice that per the above conventions, different bytestrings can decode to the same OID; however the rule in crypto (for OIDs at least) is to stick to the unique [DER encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding), such that (in the bitstring with the Value field of an OID) a byte 80<sub>h</sub> can only follow a byte which high-order bit is set (otherwise the 80<sub>h</sub> would encode leading zeroes of an integer, and must be suppressed).

---

Daniel Marschall's [*Study about OID encoding and size limitations*](http://www.viathinksoft.de/%7Edaniel-marschall/asn.1/oid_facts.html) was most useful in making the above (hopefully) correct; it also confirmed my intuition that OID decoding practices are chaotic. Microsoft has an [explanation on OID format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which I found initially useful even though it turns out to be dangerously lacking.

The normative references for OID encoding are somewhere in [IUT-T X.680 through X.695](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680/en) *Information Technology - Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1) & ASN.1 encoding rules*. They are also in its free ancestors [IUT-T X.209:1988](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.209-198811-W/en) *Specification of Basic Encoding Rules for Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)* in section 22 *Encoding of an object identifier value*, with definitions in [IUT-T X.208:1988](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.208-198811-W/en) *Specification of Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)* in section 28 *Notation for the object identifier type* and annexes B, C and D.