# OID for Ed25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, pkcs11

I am working on a code generating Edwards curve (Ed25519) keys in a HSM using PKCS#11 API. In the public key template the CKA_EC_PARAMS  uses an OID to specify the curve. The encoding for Ed25519 is 06 09 2B 06 01 04 01 DA 47 0F 01. I understand the tag (06 for OID), the length (9) but the OID itself does not match the 1.3.101.112 from the RFC8410.

Any clue ? Is this pure proprietary encoding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you need, but [`06 09 2B 06 01 04 01 DA 47 0F 01`](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#BgkrBgEEAdpHDwE) is the DER encoding of OID [1.3.6.1.4.1.11591.15.1](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.11591.15.1&action=display) meaning curve Ed25519, not the OID [1.3.101.112](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.101.112&action=display) for algorithm EdDSA25519, which DER encoding I just computed by hand as [`06 03 2B 65 70`](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#BgMrZXA).

See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29116/555) for the mysteries of OID encoding, with references, explaining in particular how `2B` turns to 1.3.

Comment: Excellent thanks. Apparently OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.11591.15.1 is introduced in OpenPGP message Format draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-09.